# Deleting directories within Android internal storage

Tags: android, kotlin, internal-storage, android-internal-storage

In order to remove a directory within Android internal storage, this is the kind of code I use.

```
    val directory = getDir("myDirName", MODE_PRIVATE) // *1.

    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        directory.delete()
    }
```

The first problem is that line *1 will create the directory in case it does not exist.

Is there a way to actually know if a directory exists or not, without creating one if it does not?

Beside, I also noticed that this code is not working one hundred percent of the time.

Is there a better way to remove a directory?

Comment: You are stil using getDir(). Better use getFilesDir().

Comment: @blackapps. Why is getFilesDir() better than getDir()?
getFilesDir() points to the files directory.
My own folders are under the root directory, not under the files directory.

Comment: Because it does not create directories like getDir(). And you can use getFilesDir().getParentFile() or getFilesDir().getParent() for what you call root. And why do you want them 'under root'?

Comment: @blackapps. I see, this is interesting I will look into that. About your question "why do you want them 'under root'?", the only answer I had was : "why not put them 'under root'?".

Answer (score 0):

You could implement something like that:

```
val directory = File("myDirName")

if (directory.exists()) {
    directory.delete()
}
```

Comment: Tell me if I am wrong but your first line will create something if it does not already exist.

Comment: No, new File() does not create any file / folder until you explicity say for example with createNewFile() or mkdir() methods. For your reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: OK, I see. But your first line does not seem to be valid Kotlin code (as far as I tried).

Comment: I corrected It. Was using wrong constructor

Comment: Thank you but it is still wrong. If I remove "new" it compiles, though the code still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

this is a method which delete your app directory

```
public boolean deleteRecursive(Context context,String filePath) {
        
        boolean result=false;

        //Create androiddeft folder if it does not exist
        File fileOrDirectory = new File(filePath);

        if (fileOrDirectory.isDirectory()) {
            for (File child : fileOrDirectory.listFiles()) {

                child.delete();
            }
        }else {
            log("Delete pdf","no directory found");
            return false;
        }

        if (fileOrDirectory.listFiles().length<2)
        {
            result=true;
        }else {
            result=false;
       }


       return  result;

    }
```